# What is the correct way of comparing two ASCII characters?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

To be honest, this is part of the problem from my homework. However, I've really tried my best but still don't get the expected output. So I come here for help.

Right now I need to sort the words in a buffer, so that they would appear in ascending order. Each word ends with a space as a separator, and the space doesn't participate in comparison.

```
char *input = (char*) malloc(bufferSize*sizeof(char));
```

//This is the buffer containing words from stdin.

Then, I use an array of pointers to store the pointer of each word:

```
char **arrayPtr = (char**) malloc(numLines*sizeof(char*));
char *ptr = input;
for(int i = 0; i < numLines; i++){ //numLines is equal to number of words.
  arrayPtr[i] = ptr;
  while(*ptr != ' ')
    ptr++;
  ptr++;
}
```

Afterwards, I call qsort to sort the words with my own function 'frobcmp' to make comparisons.

```
qsort(arrayPtr, numLines, sizeof(char*), frobcmp);

int frobcmp(const void *a, const void *b){
const char *x = *(const char**)a;
const char *y = *(const char**)b;
while(1){
   if(*x == ' ' && *y == ' ')
      return 0;
   else if(*x == ' ')
      return -1;
   else if(*y == ' ')
      return 1;
   int mask = 0x00101010;
   int byteX = (int) *x;
   int byteY = (int) *y;
   int diff = (byteX ^ mask) - (byteY ^ mask);
   if(diff) return diff;
   x++;
   y++;
  }
}
```

### The reason I have each byte ^ with mask is that these words in the buffer are frobnicated (XOR with 42). So I have to reverse these bytes to their original states before making comparison.

My question is what's wrong with my code? Why the resulting output is not in ascending order? Is there something wrong with my method for comparison?

I am sincerely looking forward somebody to giving help...
I could append more code if necessary..

Comment: Don't cast result of `malloc` and also , why are there unnecessary casts ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have:

```
int mask = 0x00101010;
```

and then you said:

> these words in the buffer are frobnicated (XOR with 42), So I have to reverse these bytes to their original states before making comparison.

However, `0x00101010` is not `42`. If that number were a binary number, it would be `42` but it's in hex.

You can use:

```
int mask = 42;
```

or

```
int mask = 0x2A;
```

Comment: Yes that is the problem. I typed too many hex numbers today so I didn't realize this stupid mistake. Thanks a lot... forgive my stupidity.

Comment: @yantiz, don't feel bad. We all have days like that.

Comment: May I ask another question? Why can't I step into qsort function when using gdb? I indeed put -g after gcc.

Comment: @yantiz, `qsort` is a standard library function for which you don't have the necessary debugging information. You can set a breakpoint in `frobcmp` to debug your code.

Comment: yantiz, you can accept the answer, see this link: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235 Don't make people read this whole page when the issue has already been resolved.

Comment: I've done that, deeply sorry for the inconvenience...Should be more familiar with the rules here